# Скрытие / отображение HTML-форм (при нажатии кнопки) с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, веб-сайт, site

помогите плиз,есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую открывается форма для ввода коммента, как сделать так, чтобы при повторном нажатии  на нее форма скрывалась

```
<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getReady);
function getReady()
{
    document.querySelectorAll('[class="collapsible"]').forEach((elem)=>
    {
        elem.addEventListener('click', click_span);
    });
}
function click_span()
{
    document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible-content').forEach((elem)=>
    {
        elem.style.display = 'none';
    });
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
}
   </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы скрывать форму при повторном нажатии на кнопку, вы можете добавить проверку, чтобы определить, открыта ли форма в данный момент. Если форма открыта, скройте ее, а если она закрыта, то покажите ее.

Вот как это можно сделать:

```html
<script>
function click_span() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible-content').forEach((elem)=> {
      elem.style.display = 'none';
    });
    
    const content = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (content.style.display === 'block') {
        content.style.display = 'none'; // Если форма открыта, скрываем её
    } else {
        content.style.display = 'block'; // Если форма закрыта, показываем её
    }
}
</script>
```

Этот код будет переключать отображение формы при каждом нажатии на кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

Метод **toggle** объекта *classList* чередует заданный CSS класс элемента: добавляет класс, если его нет и удаляет, если есть.

```
<p id="elem" class="www ggg zzz"></p>
let elem = document.querySelector('#elem');
elem.classList.toggle('zzz');
```